# React native: Do ultility styles increase performace/reduce app size?

Tags: css, react-native, themes

In web apps, we can create utility classes (using tailwind CSS, for instance) like this:

```
.p-2 {
    padding: 0.5rem !important;
}
```

And, if we have a consistent design and many elements use the same utility classes, we will decrease the CSS bundle.

But when talking about react native, what are the performance/size advantages of doing the same, but like this:

```
const style = StyleSheet.create({
  "p-2": {
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```